# How to Manipulate template content at runtime in php?

Tags: php

I want to add or manipulate the content of template through a PHP page on runtime.

For example, In my online shopping website, I have a division for shopping cart in template then how can I change that division's content through a PHP page when user add an item to cart..

I don't want to assign values to that division on each page so, I put that division in template.

Please Help me with this..
Thanking you in advance for any Interest shown..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript in order to do that - well at least if you don't want the page to reload.
There are plenty of examples all over the web (search for setting up cookie/session variable using Javascript).
Using Javascript libraries such as [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) would help you a lot.

For example:

1. User clicks on "add to cart"
2. Javascript updates a cookie variable with the item's information
3. Javascript updates content of the cart on the page

Optionally, use AJAX to communicate with the server and do something on success/error.